# How to access the the MVC model created by me in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I think now I am getting the page, but the page is showing a blank. The Url which I access is http://localhost/BookLearn/CodeIgniter-2.2.1/index.php/start

My Controller's file name is `start.php`.
And My View's file name is `testview.php`.

> Controller

```
<?php
  class Start extends CI_Controller
  {
    var $base;
    var $css;
    function Start()
    {
      date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
      parent::CI_Controller();
      $this->base = $this->config->item('base_url');
      $this->css  = $this->config->item('css');
    }

    function hello()
    {
      $data['css'] = $this->css;
      $data['base'] = $this->base;
      $data['mytitle'] = "Using CI to build a Site";
      $data['mytext'] = "Hello now Can we do some Dynamic Processing. <br /> And Ah! U Know, This Is Dynamic!!";
      return $this->load->view('testview', $data);

    }
  }
?>
```

> View

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href= <?php echo "$base"; ?> />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo "$base/$css"; ?>" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> <?php echo $mytitle; ?> 
    test</h1>
    <p class="test"> <?php echo $mytext; ?> </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: im not sure what you are trying to do ... But for base_url, why are you calling it like that? Why not use the URL helper and use `base_url()` ?

Comment: @CodeGodie Can U Please Elaboratate!

Comment: check out this page: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: also you do not need to `return` the view, remove that, all u need is `$this->load->view('testview', $data);`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You just add `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` your  `Start()` function.

you may use your time zone by replacing 'America/Los_Angeles'

**Solution 2**

You may need to put the timezone in a configuration in your php.ini file. In php.ini file should have a block like blow :

`[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/New_York`

If not, add this block of in your php.ini (replacing the timezone by yours) , make sure to restart httpd (service httpd restart).

[List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

Config.php (application/config/config.php)

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']';
```

Controller:

```
class Start extends CI_Controller {

    private $css;

    function __construct() {
        $this->css = $this->config->item('css');
    }

    function hello() {
        $data['css'] = $this->css;
        $data['mytitle'] = "Using CI to build a Site";
        $data['mytext'] = "Hello now Can we do some Dynamic Processing. <br /> And Ah! U Know, This Is Dynamic!!";
        $this->load->view('testview', $data);
    }

}
```

View:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="<?= base_url(); ?>" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= $css; ?>" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><?= $mytitle; ?> test</h1>
        <p class="test"><?= $mytext; ?> </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to define a index function in every CI class**

**Or call class function by name like : ci_root/index.php/class/function**

**http://localhost/BookLearn/CodeIgniter-2.2.1/index.php/start/hello**

You need to use `parent::__construct();` by replacing `parent::CI_Controller();`

```
<?php
class Start extends CI_Controller {
var $base;
var $css;
    function Start()
    {
      date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
      parent::__construct();
      $this->base = $this->config->item('base_url');
      $this->css  = $this->config->item('css');
    }

    function index(){
        $this->hello();
    }

    function hello()
    {
      $data['css'] = $this->css;
      $data['base'] = $this->base;
      $data['mytitle'] = "Using CI to build a Site";
      $data['mytext'] = "Hello now Can we do some Dynamic Processing. <br /> And Ah! U Know, This Is Dynamic!!";
      return $this->load->view('testview', $data);

    }
}
?>
```